# notifyCheckpointComplete is never called in Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I wrote my own operator extends from AbstractStreamOperator and OneInputStreamOperator

```
    implements OneInputStreamOperator<GenericRecord, Void> 


    @Override
    public void notifyCheckpointComplete(long checkpointId) throws Exception {
      ...
    }
```

then I transform my DataStream

```
OneOperator oneOperator = new OneOperator();
        input.transform(oneOperator.getClass().getSimpleName(), Types.VOID, oneOperator)
                .setParallelism(1)
                .setMaxParallelism(1)
                .addSink(new DiscardingSink<>())
                .setParallelism(1)
                .uid("oneOperator");
```

so that I can use the oneOperator to do something.

in my unit test, i set checkpointing to be 500ms and autowatermarkInterval to be 10, then I pass 2 events into input, the timestamp between 2 events are 2 hours apart, which is enough to trigger checkpointing.

So, in my understanding, the notifyCheckpointComplete will be called once the checkpoint is triggered.

But when I run my unit test, notifyCheckpointComplete function is never called.

Did I miss anything?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkpointing has nothing to do (most of the times) with Watermarking :) So, when You set Your checkpoiting to be 500ms it will be 500ms of processing time, so it really doesn't matter which data You inject. It is possible that the checkpoint is not triggered if the test finishes very quickly, so You may need to decrease the checkpointing time or add some sleep to wait for checkpoint to be triggered.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I want to understand more about this .

1) i followed your suggestion and decease the checkpointing time to 50. the notifyCheckpointComplete did trigger.

2) when you say add sleep, if I set breakpoint in debug mode, isn't it the same effect? Then it leads to 3)

3) That leads to the next issue. My oneOperator has another function called `public void processWatermark(Watermark watermark) ` which I would like them to be called before notifyCheckpointComplete, but after decreasing the checkpoint time, notifyCheckpointComplete is always called before processWatermark.

Comment: As for 2) it depends on Your settings, in general there is possibility to only suspend a single thread so You could technically achieve the same behaviour, but it will depend on where You actually put the breakpoint :) So, in general I'd recommend going with sleep since it's easier to do correctly. As for 3) Flink doesn't provide any guarantees for that AFAIK, so You will have to set `autoWatermarkInterval` to something very small like 100-200ms and then checkpointing time to smth like 1-2 seconds  and introduce the mentioned sleep.

Comment: Thank you. I resolved it by making the source implement checkListener and won't stop till the checkpoint count is reached. That is equivalent to your sleep. And also make sure autowatermarkInterval < checkpointing so that guarantee that processwatermark and notifyCheckpointComplete in this operator will be executed.

Thank you again for your answer, it was very helpful!